# Equalizing within tabs Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I can't figure out how to get it to work. The documentation seems a little sparser than last time and doesn't include examples. Any help would be appreciated.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html#applyheight

```
$('.tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
  // Trying to trigger equalizer to equalize
  console.log('test'); // This is working
});
```

**Update** - I think this might be closer, but it's still not working

```
var elem = new Foundation.Equalizer($('.parent-row'));
$('.tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
  elem.applyHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your content equalize if your browser is resized? If so, you can try to force it on tab selection by adding `Foundation.reInit('equalizer');` in your change.zf.tabs event handler.

Please note: I'm experiencing similar issues and found this to work..but it may not be the most optimal.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, F6's version of reflow, thanks Dany. No thanks F6 documentation.